# How do I save multiple form inputs in a file

Tags: php, html

html

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<form class="contact-form" action="contact-form.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="E-Mail">
    <br>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</html>
```

contact-form.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $data=$_POST["name, subject, mail, message"];
    $fp = fopen("data.txt", "a");
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

If I put

```
    $data=$_POST["name"];
```

It works, but I want to save multiple inputs. cant seem to make it work :(
If I put everything under eachother it only saves the last input.

Comment: What do you mean with _"but I want to save multiple inputs"_?

Comment: If I only save one input , for example name it works. But I want to save name,subject,mail and message. That doesnt work.

Comment: "_It works_"?? `$data=$_POST["name, subject, mail, message"];` does actually work? And why set `$name`, `$subject` etc. if you don't use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
$data=$_POST["name, subject, mail, message"];
```

to:

```
$data = $_POST["name"] . $_POST["mail"] . $_POST["subject"] . $_POST["message"];
```

You can also concatenate some spaces to separate the data:

```
$data = $_POST["name"] . " " . $_POST["mail"] . " " . $_POST["subject"] . " " . $_POST["message"];
```

You need to [concatenate](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/concatenation-two-string-php/) all the values of `$_POST` inside a single variable. `$_POST` works exactly like an array, and you can't get multiple array values the way you were doing.

You can get some additional information about arrays [in here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-arrays/) :)

Comment: Thanks thats it! Is there a way to space the output? Its in my data file all stackedup without spaces

Comment: Sure. Just updated my answer with an example :)

Comment: Perfect I added \n looks very good now, thank you very much!

Comment: Just a tip: Use PHP_EOL instead of \n because it works better in different operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try something like this - it'll print the field and value for any parameter present in the POST data.

```
<?php
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        foreach( $_POST as $field => $value )file_put_contents( 'data.txt', sprintf('%s: %s%s', $field, $value, PHP_EOL ), FILE_APPEND );
    }
?>
```